# Difference between MVC Model and Business Logic layer in architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture

I am new in MVC and little confuse and want to ask about **differences and purposes** of both.
 **MVC model and Business Logic layer (BLL)** in tier Architecture.

What is the purpose and need  to use **BLL**?  some say they exchange the data between Presentation layer and data access layer. except these elaborate the BLL purpose.

So, we create properties in both **MVC Model and BLL**. So mention the proper difference and similarities if it has with the relevant  code or example

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to structure an enterprise MVC app, and where does Business Logic go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568010/how-to-structure-an-enterprise-mvc-app-and-where-does-business-logic-go)

Answer (score 0):

To me the M in MVC is about the view model used by the view. Each view has its dedicated view model, that contains all information needed by the view.

These view models are built in the controllers based on the DTO's that you receive from your back-end.

The BLL you are talking about is more the business layer on the back-end, which you don't know in your front-end logic. Often people use a domain driven approach or this layer.