# ASP.NET MVC N-Tier application with WCF and entity framework efficient loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework

I am after some advice on using entity framework in an efficient way with a WCF service called from an MVC application.

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application as the presentation layer that calls through to a WCF service which does all the data manipulation. The WCF application uses entity framework to perform the operations on the DB.

The problem is that depending on the page that is being rendered the information required from the DB will change, for example if I want to show a list of all the users I might just want their username but the WCF service would return the whole model, this obviously becomes very inefficient when working with large numbers of records.

Is there any ways to make this more efficient, need to somehow be able to specify the values for Include and Select in the Linq statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you right, you're actually saying that your `Models` are not compatible with the needs of your `Views`.

That is (one of the reasons) why people are using `Data Transfer Objects (DTO)` as the objects returned from the data service, and not the entities themselves.

Usually, you will need to `project / map` your entities into the DTO object.

> for example if I want to show a list of all the users I might just
>   want their username but the WCF service would return the whole model

For this particular scenario you could try something like this:

```
// Your 'User' Entity
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

// Base class for all 'Mappable' DTOs
public abstract class Mappable<ENTITY, DTO> where ENTITY : BaseEntity
{
    public abstract DTO ToDTO(ENTITY entity);
}

// Your DTO (specific to your grid needs)
public class UsersGridDTO : Mappable<User, UsersGridDTO>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public override UsersGridDTO ToDTO(User entity)
    {
        return new UsersGridDTO
        {
            Id = entity.Id,
            Username = entity.Username
        };
    }
}

// In your WCF data service
public IEnumerable<DTO> GetData<DTO>() where DTO : Mappable<Entity, DTO>, new()
{
    return efContext.Users.Select(new DTO().ToDTO);
}
```

Also, When using Asp.Net MVC, the DTOs **can** be used as your `ViewModels` as well (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431490)).

You can also use frameworks like `AutoMapper` that can handle the Entity to DTO mapping for you.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I was after. Only other thing is, is there any way to use this approach with the eager loading of entity framework. For your example if I wanted another DTO that had the phones collection. Obviously the mapping could just reference the Phones property in the model but if its not loaded this would be another call to the DB?

Comment: Since (by default) Entity Framework is wrapping your Entity with a `Dynamic Proxy` that initiates the 'get-from-db' call on demand, the `User` entity that is being passed to `ToDTO` method is also a proxy and will be able to fill your `Phones` collection using Lazy Load.

Comment: As I understand Lazy Load will use another DB call, is this going to be performance issue with large record sets?

Comment: When dealing with large data-sets, it could be an issue. that is why you can `Eager Load` some data using the `Include` method. but that's worth another discussion.