# MediatR - Using commands/Queries as parameters to controller actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, mediator, mediatr

I am using the C# MediatR library to implement a mediator pattern to send commands and queries from my controller. As I am new to this pattern so I have been watching some online tutorials where I saw that in some cases the Mediator `Query` or `Command` classes have been passed as parameters to controller action methods and forwarded as it is to the MediatR while in some tutorials there is a separate view model passed into the controller action methods method, which is first mapped to command or query class and then forwarded to the MediatR.
**Which approach is considered better, passing Command/Query to controller action directly or using a view model instead?** Couldn't find any relevant answer yet. Any help is highly appeciated

**Command being passed into controller action parameter**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginUserCommand loginUserCommand)
    {
        var User = await _meditr.Send(loginUserCommand);

        return View();
    }
```

**ViewModel used in the controlleraction parameter**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        var authenticateUserCommand = _mapper.Map<LoginUserCommand>(loginViewModel);
        var User = await _meditr.Send(authenticateUserCommand);

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should first understand the difference between `ViewModel` and `DTO`. In most cases, the naming is wrong. A command in this context is technically a `DTO`. But it also represents something that has a special meaning in the business domain - something that shall happen, i.e. a command to be executed in the system.

Read this post to better understand :
[what is the difference between a view model and a data transfer object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431445)

But about your main question When you use `Mediatr`.
In fact, your `controller` only acts as an interface or bridge between the user and the program logic,
and only needs to establish this connection, so it receives the desired command or `Dto`, and the validation operation is
the responsibility of your `command` and `handler`. In this scenario, if you receive the data in a different way and map it to a command,
it is practically of no use and is considered overtime because you are not going to do any validation on your controller.

So this is a better option

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginUserCommand loginUserCommand)
{
    var User = await _meditr.Send(loginUserCommand);
    return View();
}
```

If you are looking for a good example, I recommend this repository :

https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture

Comment: Yeah totally makes sense because no validation is being done in the controller so there is no need for the view model to be added.  Thank you.